# Wordpress Site: background issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

First off, please forgive me if this isn't detailed enough. I am a graphic designer with minimum html/coding knowledge.

I am designing a site using WordPress. I put in a pink pattern background and it works well on the homepage. But if you click on the Print Design page for example, you'll see that the text is on top of the background, making it hard to read. Anyone know what I need to put in the code to give it a light grey color behind the text but still keep the pink pattern background on the sides?

[www.mycolorshop.com](http://www.mycolorshop.com)

Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: Use provided space to show the relevant code. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: If you're a _"graphic designer with minimum html/coding knowledge"_, then why are you doing the programming?

Comment: Sparky I'm doing it because I don't have any other choice…got to figure it out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the content in a div and change the background-color in your css to be grey.

I looked at your page, so in this case you want to add something like this to your css somewhere:

```
#content-core {
    background-color: #cccccc; /* Change this to whatever color you want */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look, you guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a transparent background that should do the trick. You may need a fallback for older browsers.

```
#content-core {
    padding: 5px; 
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a background to the content div or `p` tags inside it.

in css:

```
#main-core{
    background:#ff0000; /* or any other colour*/
}
```

or

```
#main-core p{
    background:#ff0000; /* or any other colour*/
}
```

The first one would apply the colour to the container, where as the second one only to the `p` tags, meaning any gaps will not have the background colour.